# How to transform column values into row header using Python?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I need to transform the column values to header in python.

```
    testdf = {'Student_id':['10001','10001','10001','20001','20001','30001','30001','30001'],
          'Subject':['S1','S2','S3','S1','S2','S1','S2','S3'],
          'Mark':['80','60','70','50','70','90','80','40']
         }
testdf = pd.DataFrame(data=testdf)
testdf
```

[image]

I want to have a table like

[image]

When I tried below code

```
testdf.pivot(index="Student_id",columns="Subject")
```

I am getting like below:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add parameter `values` to [`DataFrame.pivot`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html) and if necessary data cleaning - [`DataFrame.rename_axis`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rename_axis.html) for remove columns name and [`DataFrame.reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html) for column from `index`:

```
df = (testdf.pivot(index="Student_id",columns="Subject", values='Mark')
            .rename_axis(None, axis=1)
            .reset_index())
print (df)
  Student_id  S1  S2   S3
0      10001  80  60   70
1      20001  50  70  NaN
2      30001  90  80   40
```

Comment: Excellent. This is what I am exactly looking for.